# Copy a row from Sheet1 and paste it into Sheet 2 if color of a cell is green

Tags: excel, vba

I made this code to copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 if the color of the cell is green (after conditional formatting it turns green). But it is giving me error in the color condition. Any suggestions ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Interior.ColorIndex = 14 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy  
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If    
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If You are checking `Interior` of the whole `Sheet1` probly You need to put there `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 14`

Comment: Thanks!! It fixed the error but still the code is not working. I mean, it is not copying data from one sheet to another. Any solutions for that ?

Comment: Put there `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex` or `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to consider, the For Loop will iterate through column A of Sheet1 and copy the full row to Sheet2 in the next available row, if it meets the criteria:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To a
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 14 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & b).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code is giving an error. "Paste special method of range class failed".

Comment: @Nagendra I've now updated my response, it should work appropriately for you now... :)

Answer (score 0):

You set

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

So there is nothing in the buffer to paste. Move that line to after the PasteSpecial

You'd be better off not copying and pasting. When you copy/paste you muck with the user's copy/paste buffer. It's generally better to assign values and other aspects directly:

```
myTargetRange.Value = mySourceRange.Value
myTargetRange.Formula = mySourceRange.Formula
myTargetRange.RowHeight = mySourceRange.RowHeight
```

etc.